# Safe version of OS.Process.system

Tags: shell, exec, sml

Standard ML provides a function

```
val system : string -> status
```

in the [`OS.Process`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/os-process.html) which invokes the argument via the shell.

It is generally good practice to avoid the shell if one does not need its features, due to quoting complexity, security issues and whatnot. So most languages also provide a direct execution function.

I could not find something like that in Standard ML. I would expect it to have a type similar to

```
val system : string -> string list -> status
```

How do I call something not via the system shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application runs on some Unix flavor, you could use the optional [`Unix` structure](http://sml-family.org/Basis/unix.html), implemented by SML/NJ (at least):

```
val proc : (TextIO.instream, TextIO.outstream) Unix.proc =
  Unix.execute ("/bin/ls", ["-l"]);
val inStream = Unix.textInstreamOf proc;
val output = TextIO.inputAll inStream;
TextIO.closeIn inStream;
Unix.reap proc;
print output;
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume this works on Linux and OS X. I guess this structure is  available on Windows, is it?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I don't have a Windows machine to test, so I can't tell. I doubt it, though.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner The online documentation for the Unix structure ends with the tantalizing: "Implementation note:

Although the flavor of this module is heavily influenced by Unix, and the module is simple to implement given the Posix subsystem, the functions are specified at a sufficiently high-level that implementations, including non-Unix ones, could provide this module without having to supply all of the Posix modules. ". This suggests that it should be possible to make it work in Windows, although it is hard to tell ahead of time how much work it would require.

Comment: On Windows you can do almost exactly the same using the Windows structure.  This is available in Poly/ML, at least.